# Split a string on every nth character and ensure that all segment strings have the same length

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I want to split the following string into 3-letter elements.  Additionally, I want all elements to have 3 letters even when the number of characters in the inout string cannot be split evenly.

Sample string with 10 characters:

```
$string = 'lognstring';
```

The desired output:

```
$output = ['log','nst','rin','ing'];
```

Notice how the `in` late in the inout string is used a second time to make the last element "full length".

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help you.

```
$str = 'lognstring';
$arr = str_split($str, 3);

$array1= $arr;
array_push($array1,substr($str, -3));
print_r($array1);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't ensure that all elements have the same length.  https://3v4l.org/daKEt

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'lognstring';
$chunk = 3;
$arr = str_split($str, $chunk); //["log","nst","rin","g"]

if(strlen(end($arr)) < $chunk)  //if last item string length is under $chunk
    $arr[count($arr)-1] = substr($str, -$chunk);  //replace last item to last $chunk size of $str

print_r($arr);

/**
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "log"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "nst"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "rin"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "ing"
}
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Differently from the earlier posted answers that blast the string with `str_split()` then come back and mop up the last element if needed, I'll demonstrate a technique that will populate the array of substrings in one clean pass.

To conditionally reduce the last iterations starting point, either [use a ternary condition](https://3v4l.org/uGghH) or `min()`.  I prefer the syntactic brevity of `min()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2mkSm))

```
$string = 'lognstring';
$segmentLength = 3;
$totalLength = strlen($string);
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalLength; $i += $segmentLength) {
    $result[] = substr($string, min($totalLength - $segmentLength, $i), $segmentLength);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'log',
  1 => 'nst',
  2 => 'rin',
  3 => 'ing',
)
```

Alternatively, you can prepare the string BEFORE splitting (instead of after).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5Sj7P))

```
$extra = strlen($string) % $segmentLength;
var_export(
    str_split(
        $extra
            ? substr($string, 0, -$extra) . substr($string, -$segmentLength)
            : $string,
        $segmentLength
    )
);
```

Or you can just brute-force the correction on the last element. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/tLamC)

```
$str = 'lognstring';
$size = 3;
$result = str_split($str, $size);
$result[array_key_last($result)] = substr($str, -$size);
var_export($result);
```